# how to change a user defined object inside a function without assigning

Tags: python

For example I have a class with Linked list class

```
class Link:

    empty = ()

    def __init__(self, first, rest=empty):
        assert rest is Link.empty or isinstance(rest, Link)
        self.first = first
        self.rest = rest

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.rest is Link.empty:
            return 'Link({})'.format(self.first)
        else:
            return 'Link({}, {})'.format(self.first, repr(self.rest))

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns a human-readable string representation of the Link

        >>> s = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
        >>> str(s)
        '<1 2 3 4>'
        >>> str(Link(1))
        '<1>'
        >>> str(Link.empty)  # empty tuple
        '()'
        """
        string = '<'
        while self.rest is not Link.empty:
            string += str(self.first) + ' '
            self = self.rest
        return string + str(self.first) + '>'
```

Is it possible to take a Linked list object and input it into a function which will alter it without assigning

```
def func(lst):

    lst=lst.rest
```

instead of

```
def func2(lst):

    return lis.rest
```

so I could do func1(lst) and it would altered instead of lst=func2(lst)

Comment: Want do you want to obtain? Have you tried your example? what you get and what do you expect? If I correctly understand what you are doing, ``func`` seems a great way write confusing and hard to debug code!

Answer (score 0):

Because objects are mutable (by default) in Python you can modify an object but that won't change a reference in an outer scope. You can use the `id` function to test this:

```
class A:
    pass

def func1(a):
    print('From func1 before assignment ', id(a))
    a = A()
    print('From func1 after assignment ', id(a))

a = A()
print('From global scope before function ', id(a))
func1(a)
print('From global scope after function ', id(a))
```

outputs

```
From global scope before function  4646262768
From func1 before assignment  4646262768
From func1 after assignment  4646263888
From global scope after function  4646262768
```

So in `func1` we changed what the variable `a` refers to, but because it is a local variable, it doesn't change the `a` reference outside of the function's scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant trying to change an attribute of an object within a function without having to re-create that object, yes you can:

```
def change_link(lnk):
    lnk.rest = Link(10)
```

If you didn't want to use the assignment operator, you could use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
def change_link(lnk):
    setattr(lnk, 'rest', Link(10))
```

But `setattr` doesn't return anything after setting the attribute, not even the object. So doing

```
def change_link(lnk):
    return setattr(lnk, 'rest', Link(10))
```

would return `None`.

Now, if what you're really trying to do is **chain several functions which modify a `Link` object one after the other** like this:

```
modify_list(add_item(pop_first(lnk)))
```

then you need to ***modify and return*** the object from the functions:

```
>>> def insert_2nd_link(lnk):
...     lnk.rest = Link(10, lnk.rest)  # adds a new 2nd item
...     return lnk                     # return the object
...
>>> def multiply_first_by_50(lnk):
...     lnk.first *= lnk.first * 50    # modifies 1st item
...     return lnk                     # return the object
...
>>> s = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
>>> s      # original s
Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
>>> new_s = multiply_first_by_50(insert_2nd_link(s))
>>> new_s  # is it actually new? No
Link(50, Link(10, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4)))))
>>> s      # old s
Link(50, Link(10, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4)))))
>>> id(s) == id(new_s)
True
>>>
```

Note that outside your function chain, you don't need to assign the return value since it happens "in-place":

```
>>> s = Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
>>> s
Link(1, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4))))
>>> multiply_first_by_50(insert_2nd_link(s))
Link(50, Link(10, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4)))))
>>> s
Link(50, Link(10, Link(2, Link(3, Link(4)))))
>>>
```